# Не работает перевод в Django description?

Tags: python, django

На двуязычном сайте пытаюсь сделать переводимым метатег description. Делаю согласно [документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/i18n/translation/#translate-template-tag) , но перевод этой фразы "guide to all the filming locations" не работает, просто не появляется на сайте.

Код в шаблоне:

```
{% translate 'guide to all the filming locations' as guide_location %}
{% block description%}
        <meta name="description" content="{{ movie.title }} {{ movie.year }} {{ guide_location }}, {{movie.description|truncatechars:80 }} ">
{% endblock%}
```

Код в файле перевода

```
#: .\movies\templates\movies\details_view.html:8
msgid "guide to all the filming locations"
msgstr "полный гид по всем местам съемок"
```

Код отображаемый на сайте

```
<meta name="description" content="Молокососы 2007 , Молокососы снимали в Бристоле, Великобритания, Нью-Йорке, Морокко, а сцены Росс… ">
```

Comment: Не забыли выполнить compilemessages после изменения файла перевода?

Comment: Да, сделал, не работает.